# SQL Server XML Insert

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know why not all characters are translated back (Using Microsoft SQL Server 2016) when Selecting afterwards?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XML_TEST](
[XMLData] [xml] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO


INSERT INTO [dbo].[XML_TEST] VALUES ('<Attributes><Attribute name="CRYPT">&lt;&gt;&quot;&apos;&amp;</Attribute></Attributes>')
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[XML_TEST]
-- Returns <Attributes><Attribute name="CRYPT">&lt;&gt;"'</Attribute></Attributes>
```

Greetings

Tom

Comment: Select Result is <Attributes><Attribute name="CRYPT">&lt;&gt;"'</Attribute></Attributes>, &lt;,&gt; and &amp; are not translated, but the rest is.

Comment: The result is still valid XML, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is by design.  Certainly with &lt; and &gt; if you translated them, the resultant output is no longer well formed XML

Comment: Thank you both, @JonathanWillcock, now that you mention it like this, it actually makes sense.. but why would the doublequote translate then? :(